# Latent Dirichlet Allocation - understanding the posterior

Tags: bayesian, latent-variable, posterior, dirichlet-distribution

I have a problem understanding the posterior for computing LDA, stated in page 7 of [Blei (2007)](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/papers/Blei2011.pdf). From my point of view, it's not exactly consistent with Bayes' theorem, as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Statement_and_interpretation). Could anyone give me a simple explanation of how this formula was derived? I don't really understand how the $p(\beta, \theta, z, w)$ corresponds to $P(B|A)P(A)$ in Bayes theorem. I will be extremely grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean equation (2)? I think he's not using Bayes' theorem at all -- he's just using the definition of conditional probability.

Recall that if $A$, $B$ are events, then
$$
P(A | B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}.
$$
If you want to know more about conditional probability, I think the [Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) is pretty good.

Comment: That makes sense now, thanks! I don't know why I was so sure that he was using Bayes' theorem...